# Neo4jError: Run from within the transaction or use a different session

Tags: node.js, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I upgraded Neo4j (3.?.? → 4.0.3) and the neo4j-javascript-driver (1.7.6 → 4.0.2).

Without any code changes, my Node app now gets a flurry of: `Neo4jError: Queries cannot be run directly on a session with an open transaction; either run from within the transaction or use a different session.`

All I'm using is a lot of these:

```js
const result = await session.run()
// do something with result
```

As far as I know `session.run` will open a transaction, execute the statement, and commit. There should not be an open transaction afterwards. I've tried to reproduce with a small test case, with no luck. And the docs on the `neo4j-javascript-driver` are not very helpful. As it says in the docs: *"Detailed docs not available yet"*

Any ideas to what causes the error?

Comment: Is the same `session` instance being used to process multiple concurrent client requests? Each request needs its own `session` instance.

Comment: @cybersam I have this same problem but I am using neo4j 3.5. I am getting this:  Neo4jError: You cannot run more transactions on a closed session. I am not running any concurrent stuff. This happens on my startup. In my app.js I have  three function calls to neo4j which always work fine....now sometimes the third call gives me an error AND my first so does and API call ...I use postman to test the API call. All my neo4j uses the same pattern to close the session. I am not using "await" ...just session.run(...).then (...{session.close() .....})

Comment: @cybersam I have a follow up question....does the session close or remain open if you have a CATCH error?

Comment: @michael Johanasen .....did you get an answer to this question?

Comment: @cybersam I should also point out that the error occurs on my remote developement server (DigitalOcean) but not on my local machine using the same DB on the remote server but running the code from my local machine.

Comment: @MichaelE My problem appeared to be the first comment from cybersam here: I have reused the session object across sessions. Have not tested the solution yet due to time contraints, but I find it likely to be the culprit.