# Neo4jError: You cannot run more transactions on a closed session

Tags: node.js, neo4j, digital-ocean

I have this same problem as this SO question ([Neo4jError: Run from within the transaction or use a different session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389805/neo4jerror-run-from-within-the-transaction-or-use-a-different-session)) but I am using neo4j 3.5.
I am getting this: Neo4jError: You cannot run more transactions on a closed session. I am not running any concurrent stuff. This happens on attempt to access Neo4j DB after startup of my Nodejs server running on DigitalOcean. In my app.js I have two .js modules that access the neo4j DB to initialize two loki tables which always work fine for three years now and no recent changes have been made to those modules.

The nodejs server starts up fine but when I make an API call that access the DB, I use postman to test the API call (or from my Angular app), I get this error. All my neo4j calls uses the same pattern to close the session. I use the following pattern:

```
router.updateCountryTable = (data, callback) => {

     commons.session.run(`WITH $paramCountry AS countries

                         UNWIND countries AS country

                         MATCH (c:Country)  WHERE c.countryCurrencyCode = country[0]

                         SET c.baseCurrencyXrate = country[1], c.createdAt = $paramCreatedAt

                         RETURN c AS Countries`,

                           {

                            paramCountry: data,

                            paramCreatedAt: moment().format()

                      })

                    .then( result => {

                        commons.session.close();

                        if (!result.records[0]) {

                         return callback("error...there is no country in db");

                        }

                       // response = userData.records[0].get('user').properties;

                       return callback(null, result)

                     })

                    .catch((err) => callback(err.stack))

                    

  }
```

This is a stack trace of the error:

```
Neo4jError: You cannot run more transactions on a closed session.
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at captureStacktrace (/ng-app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/result.js:199:15)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at new Result (/ng-app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/result.js:65:19)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at Session._run (/ng-app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/session.js:154:14)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at Session.run (/ng-app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/session.js:130:19)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at Function.router.updateCountryTable (/ng-app/server/model/user.js:126:22)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at /ng-app/server/model/pdmanagement.js:113:27
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at IncomingMessage.resp.on (/ng-app/server/model/user.js:95:18)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
7/29/2020 7:00:00 AM    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I am a lost because I don't get this error running the code from my local machine using the DB on DigitalOcean....only when I run the code on DigitalOcean.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

EDIT:
my session is created here.... commons/index.js

```
.......
.......
const driver = neo4j.driver(config.neo4jURL, neo4j.auth.basic(config.neo4jUSER, config.neo4jPASS));

const session = driver.session();


exports.session = session;
......
```

My db calls are in user.js:

```
.......
const commons = require('../commons');
......
......
  router.getCountryFxRates = (data, callback) => {
     commons.session.run(`MATCH (c:Country) RETURN c AS Countries`)
                    .then( result => {
                       commons.session.close();
                       if (!result.records[0]) {
                        return callback("Possible data corruption..there is no country in db");
                       }
                      const countriesArray = result.records.map(obj => obj.get('Countries').properties);
                      
                   
                    return callback(null, countriesArray)
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      console.log(`COUNTRY FX RATES DB ERROR: ${err}`);
                      return callback(err.stack)
                    })
}
 // Update Country FX table
 router.updateCountryTable = (data, callback) => {
     commons.session.run(`WITH $paramCountry AS countries
                         UNWIND countries AS country
                         MATCH (c:Country)  WHERE c.countryCurrencyCode = country[0]
                         SET c.baseCurrencyXrate = country[1], c.createdAt = $paramCreatedAt
                         RETURN c AS Countries`,
                           {
                            paramCountry: data,
                            paramCreatedAt: moment().format()
                      })
                    .then( result => {
                        commons.session.close();
                        if (!result.records[0]) {
                         return callback("Possible data corruption..there is no country in db");
                        }
                       // response = userData.records[0].get('user').properties;
                       return callback(null, result)
                     })
                    .catch((err) => callback(err.stack))
                    
  }
```

Comment: After `commons.session.close()` is called, you cannot re-use the same `Session` instance. Since `router.updateCountryTable` does not assign a new `Session` to `commons.session`, are you actually doing that elsewhere *before* each call to `router.updateCountryTable`?

Comment: @cybersam This I understand...and that is the problem, I am not using the same session anywhere without call a new  session......

Comment: `commons/index.js` will only be executed *once*.

Comment: @cybersam I edit the question to include the modules that creates the session and calls the DB. It was my understanding that every call to commons.session.run gives me a session that was closed before. If my understanding is wrong then it has been working when it shouldn't.  I understand you to be saying I am using the same session for each router.xxxxx call. If this is so then am I not closing it after each use? My alternative would be to export the driver and do session = driver.session in each router.xxxx and then close session and driver???

Comment: See my answer, which is essentially the same as your last proposal.

Comment: @cybersam .... "commons/index.js will only be executed once"  ...yes but can't we close and resuse the same session?.....this was my understanding!

Comment: @cybersam so my bigger question is why it worked until now and why it still works while running the the code on my local machine??

Comment: Probably a bug that has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

[UPDATED]

`commons/index.js` is only executed *once*, so your code is re-using the same `Session` even after it has been closed.

Here is one solution.

1. Change `commons/index.js` to this:

   ```
   .......
   const driver = neo4j.driver(config.neo4jURL, neo4j.auth.basic(config.neo4jUSER, config.neo4jPASS));

   exports.driver = driver;
   ......
   ```
2. Insert this as the first statement in the callback functions of  `getCountryFxRates` and `updateCountryTable`:

   ```
   const session = commons.driver.session();
   ```
3. In `user.js`, replace "commons.session" with "session".
4. In `user.js`, the `catch()` callbacks should also be calling "session.close()".

Comment: I know this is the best answer we have now but it doesn't compute.....In my app.js I have calls to two .js modules that access two separate router.xxxx functions from user.js with the same session.close() pattern. If this answer is the answer then the second .js module should fail...it doesn't. Maybe the fellows at Neo4j needs to look at this?

Comment: I wrote a bit too hastily. Item #2 in my answer has been updated.